# Can't pass Tekton's Getting Started. TaskRun's are not actually running

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, tekton

I'm at the finish line of this tutorial on my Linux machine with minikube: https://tekton.dev/docs/getting-started/. But something went wrong and I don't get the expected `echo` result.

In order to track the TaskRun progress run:

```
➜  TWOC tkn task start hello && sleep 5 &&  kubectl get pods && tkn taskrun list
TaskRun started: hello-run-rjd2l

In order to track the TaskRun progress run:
tkn taskrun logs hello-run-rjd2l -f -n default
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
twoc-backend-local-deployment-55b494d4cb-fjz6v   3/3     Running   12         7d22h
twoc-backend-local-deployment-55b494d4cb-vdtv5   3/3     Running   12         7d22h
NAME              STARTED   DURATION   STATUS
hello-run-5f4qc   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-5zck9   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-8sdmx   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-bvhdg   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-cdhz8   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-frbwf   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-pzvbz   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-q57p9   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-rjd2l   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-tpnt7   ---       ---        ---

➜  TWOC kubectl describe taskrun hello-run-5zck9 
Name:         hello-run-5zck9
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  tekton.dev/v1beta1
Kind:         TaskRun
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-01-06T17:34:43Z
  Generate Name:       hello-run-
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  tekton.dev/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:generateName:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:resources:
        f:serviceAccountName:
        f:taskRef:
          .:
          f:name:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:podName:
    Manager:         kubectl-create
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-01-06T17:34:43Z
  Resource Version:  180093
  Self Link:         /apis/tekton.dev/v1beta1/namespaces/default/taskruns/hello-run-5zck9
  UID:               a9353809-44c0-4864-b131-f1ab52ac080d
Spec:
  Resources:
  Service Account Name:  
  Task Ref:
    Name:  hello
Events:    <none>
➜  TWOC tkn taskrun logs --last -f 
Error: task hello create has not started yet or pod for task not yet available
➜  TWOC kubectl describe task hello             
Name:         hello
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  tekton.dev/v1beta1
Kind:         Task
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-01-06T16:28:46Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  tekton.dev/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:steps:
    Manager:      kubectl-create
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2021-01-06T16:28:46Z
    API Version:  tekton.dev/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2021-01-06T17:34:07Z
  Resource Version:  180053
  Self Link:         /apis/tekton.dev/v1beta1/namespaces/default/tasks/hello
  UID:               4dc3e52e-4407-4921-8365-7e8845eb8c6b
Spec:
  Steps:
    Args:
      Hello World!
    Command:
      echo
    Image:  ubuntu
    Name:   hello
Events:     <none>
➜  TWOC git:(master) ✗ kubectl get pods --namespace tekton-pipelines
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tekton-dashboard-6884b7b896-qtx4t              1/1     Running   3          8d
tekton-pipelines-controller-7c5494d584-d6gkn   1/1     Running   5          8d
tekton-pipelines-webhook-59c94c5c6d-nh8wc      1/1     Running   3          8d
➜  TWOC git:(master) ✗ kubectl get pods                                                   
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
twoc-backend-local-deployment-55b494d4cb-fjz6v   3/3     Running   9          7d20h
twoc-backend-local-deployment-55b494d4cb-vdtv5   3/3     Running   9          7d20h
```

Comment: This message "task hello create has not started yet or pod for task not yet available" typically means that the command `tkn taskrun logs --last -f` was run before the container had started. It typically works if you run the same command a few seconds later. Or did you get the same problem later as well?

Comment: @Jonas I waited pod start for a minutes

Comment: I can not reproduce this in my minikube. The command `tkn taskrun logs hello-run-<random> -f` gives the described output for me. I get `[hello] Hello World!`. I tested a few TaskRuns and it works. My Minikube version: v1.16.0. Tekton Pipelines v0.19.0 and latest version of `tkn`. Can you list the pods with `kubectl get pods` and perhaps try to show the logs with kubectl using `kubectl logs <pod-name>` ?

Comment: any more on this?

Comment: Yes, problem still is here

Comment: What output did you get from `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl logs <podname>` ?

Comment: Added to the question `kubectl get pods`. Logs from which pod are you asking about?

Comment: The pod for the taskRun is no longer there, since completed pods is cleaned up. If you start a new taskRun of the hello-task with: `tkn task start hello` and after that do `kubectl get pods` and after that you can see a pod with similar name as the taskRun, and do `kubectl logs <podname>` on that pod - that should show the log you are looking for.

Comment: After `tkn task start hello` I get `tkn taskrun logs hello-run-cdhz8 -f -n default`. But when I try to run this command I get `Error: task hello create has not started yet or pod for task not yet available`.

Comment: Try `kubectl get pods` and `kubectl logs <podname>` to see the logs

Comment: `kubectl get pods`'s result is in the bottom of question. `kubectl logs` of each of the pods giving common logs for my web app

Comment: The `kubectl get pods` output only shows some app, it does not show the pod from the TaskRun, you must first start a TaskRun with `tkn task start hello`

Comment: How does your `tkn taskrun list` look?

Comment: I've put answers for your two last answers at the top of the answer's code block

Comment: Btw I use Manjaro 20.2.1

Comment: I only see output from `tkn taskrun start hello` it looks like you run the commands at the same time, before any pod is created, you must wait a few seconds so the Pod is created before listing pods, the same with logs.

Comment: Updated command at the top of code block

Comment: Thanks. It looks like no Pods is created. I wounder if your Tekton Pipeline is properly installed. Do you see any errors in the log from the Pipeline Controller pod? Try `kubectl logs tekton-pipelines-controller-7c5494d584-d6gkn` and see if you see any errors

Comment: Yes, there are tons of same entries like `E0114 13:32:17.936336       1 reflector.go:125] runtime/asm_amd64.s:1357: Failed to list *v1alpha1.Task: conversion webhook for tekton.dev/v1beta1, Kind=Task failed: Post "https://tekton-pipelines-webhook.tekton-pipelines.svc:443/?timeout=30s": dial tcp 10.101.106.201:443: connect: connection refused
`

Comment: "dial tcp 10.101.106.201:443: connect: connection refused" sound like some connectivity problems.

Comment: it looks like an address from private subnet. It's not about external connections? Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think there only should be connections within the cluster, yes

Comment: So, I have trouble with cluster internal connections and it's still the problem I can't solve. I need to resolve it and pass the guide. Any ideas about how to repair the connections?

Comment: I would try to uninstall and then install again...

Comment: Ok, I'm going to reinstall minikube and tekton and then I'll bring updates here

Comment: Same problem is still here. And no idea whose IP is 10.101.106.201

Comment: I have no such errors in my Minikube. What version of Kubernetes, Minikube and Tekton do you have? E.g. `kubectl version` and `tkn version`

Comment: It is strange that it works for me but for you, are you sure that you use the same versions as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Jonas enlightened me that there is an error with the internal network of my minikube that we're not able to solve and I decided to create a GKE cluster which allowed me to successfully pass the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This listing of the TaskRuns:

```
NAME              STARTED   DURATION   STATUS
hello-run-5f4qc   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-5zck9   ---       ---        ---
hello-run-8sdmx   ---       ---        ---
```

and no corresponding created Pods indicate that your Pipeline Controller does not work properly. Inspect the logs of your controller to see if there are any related issues, e.g. with `kubectl logs tekton-pipelines-controller-7c5494d584-d6gkn`.

This error from the logs:

> Kind=Task failed: Post "https://tekton-pipelines-webhook.tekton-pipelines.svc:443/?timeout=30s": dial tcp 10.101.106.201:443: connect: connection refused

indicate that there are some connectivity problems.

When I followed the guide with Minikube on my machine, it worked without problems.

Answer (score 0):

some time you just have to restart minikube.

```
minikube start
```